# append HTML to the DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, append

OK so I'm appending HTML elements to the DOM with this following javascript..

```
$h.each(domNodes, function(domNode) {
  var input;
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('id', 'image-file');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'files[]');
    input.style.display = 'none';
    domNode.addEventListener('click', function(){
      input.style.opacity = 0;
      input.style.display='block';
      input.focus();
      input.click();
      input.style.display='none';
    }, false);
    domNode.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

And this creates a line of HTML that looks like this...

```
  <input type="file" id="image-file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;" />
```

What would the javascript look like to create HTML output that looks like this...

```
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="image-file" multiple />
 <label class="file-button" for="image-file" >
    <img src="img/upload.png" alt="add"> Upload Your File(s)
 </label>
```

I'm not sure how to nest HTML tags within other HTML tags with pure javascript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should begin by [creating a DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) and then you can append each of the child elements to that before inserting the fragment into the DOM.

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var input = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
var img = document.createElement("img");
docFragment.appendChild(input);
docFragment.appendChild(label);
label.appendChild(img);

var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.appendChild(docFragment);
```

> [DocumentFragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment) are DOM Nodes. They are never part of the main DOM
>   tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append
>   elements to the document fragment and then append the document
>   fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is
>   replaced by all its children.
>
> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM
>   tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation
>   of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document
>   fragments often results in better performance.

Answer (score 1):

The construction of the individual elements as dom nodes without any content does not change. Assemble the individual parts by employing the `appendChild` and `createTextNode` methods as follows:

```
var input, img, label, text;

input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
input.setAttribute('id', 'image-file');
input.setAttribute('name', 'files[]');
input.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');

label = document.createElement('img');
label.setAttribute('class', 'file-button');
label.setAttribute('for', 'image-file');

img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'img/upload.png');
img.setAttribute('alt', 'add');

text = document.createTextNode(' Upload Your File(s)');

label.appendChild(img);
label.appendChild(text);
domNode.appendChild(input);
domNode.appendChild(label);
```

**Notes**

- You probably want to use a `documentFragment` container for new DOM portions, see Dave Anderson's answer.
- If you can use jquery, there is a simple alternative:

-

```
var htmlfrag = $(
    '<input type="file" name="files[]" id="image-file" multiple />\n'
  + '<label class="file-button" for="image-file" >\n'
  + '    <img src="img/upload.png" alt="add"> Upload Your File(s)\n'
  + '</label>\n'
);
```

- Instead of the `$` function, [`$.parseHtml()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) might be preferable as it preserves whitespace as used in the string literal.
- Attributes on the elements can also be set using json objects; this might be preferable as the attribute set and their values can be compiled programmatically in an easier way.

(Kudos for 2 the latter aspects to Dave Anderson)

Comment: He's removed the jQuery tag.

Comment: This is a good thought, but I actually need to use pure javascript to get this done

Comment: If you just have a big string [$.parseHtml()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) works better otherwise settings attributes is best done with a JSON object `$('<input/>', { "type":"file", "id":"image-file" })`.

Comment: @DaveAnderson Thanks for the hints, adding them to the jquery part of the answer.

Comment: A variation of this example was exactly what I was looking for, this was enough to push me in the correct direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same as you did above, except you have to append the img element to the label element before appending the label to the domNode